# python regexp help

Tags: python, regex, url

Good day. Little question about reg exp.

I have a string look like

```
http://servercom/smth/Age=&amp;Filter=2&amp;
```

How can i cut `&amp;` with regexp from url?

After regexp url-string must be `http://server.com/smth/Age=1&Filter=2&`

Comment: solved 

    f = str(urlp) + str(r[0]).replace('&amp;', '&')

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Don't forget to check an answer accepted :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regex for that:

```
changed = str.replace('&amp;', '&');
```

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: But how it use.
I get string Age=&amp;Filter=2&amp with using a regexp
How can i add str.replace to regexp


exmaple


r = re.findall(r'<p><a href="[ \t\n\r]*(.*?)"', data,)
ch = str.replace('&amp;', '&', r[0])

Answer (score 2):

You are translating XML escaped special characters. Use the standard lib:

```
>>> u = "http://servercom/smth/Age=&amp;Filter=2&amp;
>>> import xml.sax.saxutils
>>> xml.sax.saxutils.unescape(u)
'http://servercom/smth/Age=&Filter=2&'
```